# CSV file lines Date string changed when running My PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

i have this csv file.

```
"date","time","user","remip","srcip","action","dstip","service","dstintf"
"2022-12-13","04:09:38","was@sil.atlas.pk","10.10.50.182","","tunnel-up","","",""
"2022-12-13","04:09:38","was@sil.atlas.pk","10.10.50.182","","tunnel-up","","",""
"2022-12-13","04:09:38","was@sil.atlas.pk","","10.212.134.200","auth-logon","","",""
"2022-12-13","04:09:57","was@sil.atlas.pk","10.10.50.182","","tunnel-down","","",""
"2022-12-13","04:09:57","was@sil.atlas.pk","10.10.50.182","","tunnel-down","","",""
"2022-12-13","04:09:57","was@sil.atlas.pk","","10.212.134.200","auth-logout","","",""
"2022-12-13","04:09:57","was@sil.atlas.pk","10.10.50.182","","tunnel-down","","",""
```

I want to calculate Time duration from my below mentioned PowerShell script, and the script is doing this task perfectly but as you can see My date entries got changed after calculations, i think this is because of date expression is applying on my entire csv lines, so is there any way to calculate only time duration without changing date entries? Any Help Please.

This is my script

```
$original_file = "F:\SIL\SILTempVPN\vpnlogs2.csv"
$destination_file = "F:\SIL\SILTempVPN\vpnlogs2.csv"
(Get-Content $original_file) | Foreach-Object {
    $_ -replace 'date','Date' `
       -replace 'dstintf','CompanyNetwork' `
       -replace 'user', 'VPNUserName' `
       -replace 'time', 'Time' `
       -replace 'srcip', 'VPNIPAssigned'`
       -replace 'tunnel-up', 'ITRC VPN User Connected'`
       -replace 'tunnel-Down', 'ITRC VPN User shutdown'`
       -replace 'action', 'VPNStatus'`
              -replace 'remip', 'RemoteIPofUser'
    } | Set-Content $destination_file



$csvdata = Get-Content -Path "F:\SIL\SILTempVPN\vpnlogs2.csv"                      |
           ConvertFrom-Csv                             |
           select @{Name="Time"; Expression={[DateTime] $_.time}},
                  RemoteIPofUser,
                  VPNIPAssigned,
                  VPNUserName,
                  VPNStatus,
                  CompanyNetwork,                                                     
                  dstip,
                  Service,
                  @{Name="TimeSpan"; Expression={""}}
$h = @{}
$csvdata | ForEach-Object {
  $key = $_.RemoteIPofUser + ';' + $_.VPNUserName; 
  if ($_.VPNStatus -like '*connected') {
    $h[$key] = $_.time
    return
  } 

  if ($h.ContainsKey($key) -and $_.VPNStatus -like '*shutdown') {
    $_.timespan = $_.time - $h[$key]
    $h.remove($key)
  }
}
$csvdata | export-csv -Path "F:\SIL\SILTempVPN\vpnlogs2.csv"
```

Result in csv file with changed date

```
"Time","RemoteIPofUser","VPNIPAssigned","VPNUserName","VPNStatus","CompanyNetwork","dstip","service","TimeSpan"
"16-Dec-22 4:09:38 AM","10.10.50.182","","was@sil.atlas.pk","ITRC VPN User Connected","","","",""
"16-Dec-22 4:09:38 AM","","10.212.134.200","was@sil.atlas.pk","auth-logon","","","",""
"16-Dec-22 4:09:57 AM","10.10.50.182","","was@sil.atlas.pk","ITRC VPN User shutdown","","","","00:00:19"
"16-Dec-22 4:09:57 AM","","10.212.134.200","was@sil.atlas.pk","auth-logout","","","",""
"16-Dec-22 4:09:57 AM","10.10.50.182","","was@sil.atlas.pk","ITRC VPN User shutdown","","","",""
```

Desired output is like this

```
"Time","RemoteIPofUser","VPNIPAssigned","VPNUserName","VPNStatus","CompanyNetwork","dstip","service","TimeSpan"
"13-Dec-22 4:09:38 AM","10.10.50.182","","was@sil.atlas.pk","ITRC VPN User Connected","","","",""
"13-Dec-22 4:09:38 AM","","10.212.134.200","was@sil.atlas.pk","auth-logon","","","",""
"13-Dec-22 4:09:57 AM","10.10.50.182","","was@sil.atlas.pk","ITRC VPN User shutdown","","","","00:00:19"
"13-Dec-22 4:09:57 AM","","10.212.134.200","was@sil.atlas.pk","auth-logout","","","",""
"13-Dec-22 4:09:57 AM","10.10.50.182","","was@sil.atlas.pk","ITRC VPN User shutdown","","","",""
```

Comment: I recommend showing what your expected result should look like, as your approach is overcomplicated. You completely change your sample CSV with your text replacement and it isn’t really helping you. You can change the property names on export.

Comment: @Doug Thank you very much for your reply i have updated my desired output please see and help

Comment: You never take the `Date` column into account when doing `Time`, so it's defaulting to the current day. Try `@{l='DateTime';e={($_.date + ' ' + $_.time) -as [datetime]}}` or something like that.